# How to scale a centered image in order to fill its parent?

Tags: css

How do I resize/scale a centered image to fill its parent when the parent container dimensions are unknown?

No cropping or stretching, just resize or scale until image fills its parent width or height.

See the below layouts ([codepen](https://codepen.io/_miki_/pen/xxrZLGd) for reference):

[image]

The child image fits its parent container as expected when at least one dimension of the child exceeds one dimension of the parent, but I cannot get the image to stretch and fill the parent when the image is smaller in both dimensions than its container (see 150x150 and 150x50 cases).

Hod do I achieve image filling its parent for all cases using CSS only?

My css for reference (see link to codepen above):

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: gray;

  display: inline-block;
}
.square {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.tall {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}
.wide {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you heard about CSS property `object-fit`?

Comment: And for your centering you should take a look at flexbox.

Comment: `height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;`

Comment: @VincentM That did it - if you post an answer (maybe with the codepen modified) I'll be happy to accept it. I had to change the child to be relative pos though.

Comment: Nice, no worries. Looks like the question is closed because a similar question has been answered before. But all good, glad I could help.